# Is there any way to sorting digit based number without using sort() in python?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have a Input value

```
 9,100,4,47,30,399,57,6,10
```

output value

```
10,100,30,399,4,47,57,6,9
```

Need to done without sorting value.

I have try this

```
l = [9,100,4,47,30,399,57,6,10]

for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(l)):

        if l[i] > l[j]:
           l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]

print l
```

Comment: Using the built-in `sorted` function, you could simply do: `sorted(l, key=lambda x: str(x))` to do an ordinary string-based sort.

Comment: See [Sorting Algorithms In Python](https://stackabuse.com/sorting-algorithms-in-python/) and pick an implementation.

Comment: the same above function can we write user defined base.

Comment: I have seen but provide same sort() which is okay but above lamda() provide digit based sorting so any github code are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are asking how to modify your code to perform a string based sort on the digits? This can be done by comparing string versions of the numbers, i.e. `str(l[i]) > str(l[j])`

```
l = [9,100,4,47,30,399,57,6,10]

for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(l)):
        if str(l[i]) > str(l[j]):
            l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]

print(l)
```

**Output**

```
[10, 100, 30, 399, 4, 47, 57, 6, 9]
```